# R: Cleaning GGally Plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language and I am new the GGally library. I followed some basic tutorials online and ran the following code:

```
#load libraries

library(GGally)
library(survival)
library(plotly)
```

I changed some of the data types:

```
#manipulate the data
data(lung)
data = lung
data$sex = as.factor(data$sex)
data$status = as.factor(data$status)
data$ph.ecog = as.factor(data$ph.ecog)
```

Now I visualize:

```
#make the plots

#I dont know why, but this comes out messy
ggparcoord(data,  groupColumn = "sex")

#Cleaner
ggparcoord(data)
```

Both ggparcoord() code segments successfully ran, however the first one came out pretty messy (the axis labels seem to have been corrupted). Is there a way to fix the labels?

In the second graph, it makes it difficult to tell how the factor variables are labelled on their respective axis (e.g. for the "sex" column, is "male" the bottom point or is "female" the bottom type). Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this?

Finally, is there a way to use the "ggplotly()" function for "ggally" objects?

e.g.

```
a = ggparcoord(data)
ggplotly(a)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your data columns get converted to a factor when adding the `groupColumn`. To prevent that you could exclude the `groupColumn` from the `columns` to be plotted:

BTW: Not sure about the general case. But at least for `ggparcoord` `ggplotly` works.

```r
library(GGally)
library(survival)
data(lung)
data = lung
data$sex = as.factor(data$sex)
data$status = as.factor(data$status)
data$ph.ecog = as.factor(data$ph.ecog)

#I dont know why, but this comes out messy
ggparcoord(data, seq(ncol(data))[!names(data) %in% "sex"], groupColumn = "sex")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply! suppose the "sex" column was labelled as "M" and "F". How would i know which would be reassigned as "1" vs "0"?